# Remaining Space on PDF Page

Tags: c#, itext7

I am currently designing a report for a customer and I have to place a text at the bottom of the last page. I have to do it while generating each quarter for 16k pdfs.

iText 7.1.5 is used, but will be upgraded to the latest version with the next release.

Doing it with a Footer on every page is not an option because the paragraph can have up to 14 lines of text. Adding a normal paragraph at the end of the document is also no solution because my client requested that the text is on top of the footer.

The expected result:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/wn3lxEr]

current generation of PDFs

```
PdfADocument pdf = new PdfADocument(...)
...
// handler for adding header and footer on every page
pdf.AddEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, headerFooterHandler);

Document doc = new Document(pdf);
doc.SetTopMargin(ConversionUtility.MillimeterToPoint(48));
doc.SetLeftMargin(ConversionUtility.MillimeterToPoint(26));
doc.SetRightMargin(ConversionUtility.MillimeterToPoint(18));
doc.SetBottomMargin(ConversionUtility.MillimeterToPoint(26));

... Some customer specific code

// paragraphs and data table is added
foreach(var feeLine in feeList.Values) {
    switch (feeLine.Type) {
        case "U":
        case "T1":
        case "T2":
        case "BS":
            doc.Add(GenerateTextBlock(feeLine, CheckSameType(feeLine.Type, feeList, i)));
            break;
        case "U3":
            doc.Add(GenerateTextBlock(feeLine, CheckSameType(feeLine.Type, feeList, i)));
            GenerateTableBlockStart(GetColumnCount(feeList[i + 1]));
            break;
        default:
            if (CheckEndOfTable(feeList, i)) {
                var table = GenerateTableBlock(feeLine, ColumnCount, true);
                doc.Add(table);
                table.Complete();
            } else {
                GenerateTableBlock(feeLine, ColumnCount, false);
            }
            break;
    }
}

headerFooterHandler.WritePageTotal(pdf);
doc.Close();
```

I would need some advise / piece of code how to find the remaining space on the last page. Placing and writing the text is no problem.

Comment: How do you add material to your PDF? Only via adding highlevel objects (paragraphs, tables, ...) to a `Document`? Or also via arbitrary `PdfCanvas` operations? If only via a `Document`, do you use a custom `DocumentRenderer`?

Comment: I only use highlevel objects. PdfCanvas only for Header and Footer. I also added some code to show you how i generate the pdfs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you fill the main page area only using a `Document` with a default `DocumentRenderer`, you can simply query the current area of the document renderer.

E.g. this piece of code writes into each line the bounding box of available space before drawing the line in question:

```
using (PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(@"DetermineRemainingSpace.pdf"))
using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter))
using (Document document = new Document(pdfDocument))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        Rectangle currentBox = document.GetRenderer().GetCurrentArea().GetBBox();
        string current = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:F}×{1:F} from ({2:F}, {3:F}) to ({4:F}, {5:F})", currentBox.GetWidth(), currentBox.GetHeight(),
                currentBox.GetLeft(), currentBox.GetBottom(), currentBox.GetRight(), currentBox.GetTop());
        document.Add(new Paragraph(string.Format("{0:D2}, previously available {1}", i, current)));
    }
}
```

The output:

[image: screen shot]

Thus,

> I would need some advise / piece of code how to find the remaining space on the last page. Placing and writing the text is no problem.

simply query the document renderer current area as above after all regular content has been added to the document.

Comment: I will test this in the next few days but look like the piece of code i have searched for :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the absolute positioning to position the text right where you want for the last page. All you need to know is to find the position where you want to place the paragraph. This can be done by opening any pdf in a PDF Reader such as Adobe / Foxit Reader and changing the ruler to points. Now all you need is to zoom in and find the position where you want to place the text. For example

```
`string dest = "destination pdf's path"
//Initialize PDF Writer
writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
//Initialize PDF Document
pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
// Initialize document
document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A4);
//You page text here
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("bla bla bla bla ");
document.Add(p);
//Write what ever you want to write on the page...
.
.
Paragraph footer = new Paragraph("some text")
footer.SetFixedPosition(72f, 50f, 500f); 
footer.SetFontSize(6f);
document.Add(footer);
document.Close();`
```

Comment: Hi, i am searching for a solution to do it for 16k pdfs each quarter. So this is technically right but isn't a solution for my problem. I will edit my question to reflect this requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, Can you please elaborate how are you generating the pdfs you have mentioned. Like are you adding text paragraphs and table etc sequentially such that you know when you are at the last page?

Comment: Adding paragraphs and data tables sequentially and only workiing with high level object. Added some code to give you an idea how i add the elements to the pdf

Comment: Thanks for the visualization of the code. What I have understood is that you add things to the document by the foreach loop and when the loop has run through all items the code exits from the loop and now writes the footer. That was exactly what I was trying to tell you. Footers and Headers are added such that regular text does not coincide with them. So you can position the footer / header at a margin that does not interfere with the regular text of the pdf. In this way you would be placing the footer on the last page below the regular margins of the pdf. Hope it helps

Comment: i have to ensure when i am writing the footer that i don't write into the content of the pdf.
Because i have set the bottom margin to a smaller value than needed on the last page. This is because i don't need the extra space on the previous pages.

Comment: [Current Cursor Position on a Page](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/faq/technical-support/itext-7/how-find-out-current-cursor-position-page) This might also help

Comment: This code snippet could be the solution for the problem. i have to try it. Thank you ! didn't found it when searched through the itext homepage.